# How to watch a change in Gerrit

Tags: gerrit, pull-request

I have made a pull request on my organisation's Gerrit. For some reason, I didn't get notified of a review or a comment on this proposed change, and it doesn't appear as watched by me.

How can I watch it, to be notified ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was the following.

Theoretically, when you push changes on Gerrit, you are automatically watching these changes.

The problem for me was that surprisingly, my Gerrit account had not picked up my email address.

Problem was fixed by going to account settings and adding my email address.

Answer (score 2):

There aren't "pull requests" in Gerrit... I suppose you have pushed some commit to refs/for/, is it correct? Please add your push command to your question.

You can see at the Gerrit UI if everything is OK by looking at:

**My** > **Changes** > **Outgoing reviews**

I don't know what is the Gerrit review strategy for your organization, I mean, I don't know if there's some hook/plugin in place to add reviewers automatically or if there're people continuously watching for new changes... but maybe you need manually add reviewers for your change.

I think it's good to ask the Gerrit administrators for directions...